# Unity: How many Raycasts per Sphere Collider?

Tags: unity, raycasting, collider

I understand that a simple sphere collider in Unity is a raycast in all directions with a certain length. How many Raycast events does a sphere collider trigger? At what degree increments are the rays cast?

Comment: Can you cite a source for your understanding that a sphere collider is a raycast in all directions? This would be a very strange way to implement this collision primitive.

Comment: Sorry, just some guy on gamedev. I wouldn't know who anymore.

Comment: I'd caution against trusting such hearsay. There's a lot of superstitious claims out there about gamedev generally and Unity in particular that don't stand up to experiments in practice.

Comment: Sphere colliders are *not* a finite number of raycasts. They're calculated as a distance. If you subtract a sphere collider's radius and add that radius to all other colliders, the sphere can be treated as a point object (which is far, far faster to compute).

Comment: Welp.. If someone wants to edit the question, go ahead. Otherwise it seems like I gotta delete it. I wanted to program a cone shaped collider myself using raycasts and I wondered what would be faster, a few raycasts or a sphere collider with an angle. I guess I'll just test it.

Answer (score 2):

Not always a raycast. Unity3D's collision is based on PhysX and it support multiple types of geometry queries:

- **raycasts** test a ray against a geometry object.
- **sweeps** move one geometry object along a line to find the first point of intersection with another geometry object.
- **overlaps** determine whether two geometry objects intersect.

How unity technologies implements every one of them is not exposed as far as i know.

[in-depth doc on PhysX](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/guide/Manual/GeometryQueries.html#)